# matrix multiplication error in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following two numpy arrays:

```
np.random.seed(1)
y2=np.random.standard_normal((50,1))
lambda_=np.zeros((100,2));
lambda_[0]=np.random.gamma(1,1,2);
```

but when I try to do

```
np.dot(y2,lambda_[0])
```

or its transposed version:

```
np.dot(y2,lambda_[0].T)
```

I get the error ValueError: matrices are not aligned

Now I understand that I can circumvent this error by using numpy matrices but isn't converting to np.matrix going to be inefficient? I am new to python so maybe I am wrong. Just trying to write the fastest code possible.

Comment: Even with `matrix` the arrays have to have compatible shapes.

Comment: Considering that y2 is a 50x1 and lambda_[0] is a 1x2 matrix they are compatible shapes in that the matrix math is correct. I was hoping that atleast the transpose would have worked.

Comment: If `lambda_` was a `matrix` its `[0]` would be `(1,2)` and compatible.  But the `array` form looses a dimension upon indexing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`y2` has the shape `(50, 1)`, and `lambda_[0]` has the shape `(2,)`, so `dot()` treats it as a matrix-vector multiplication and, consequently, throws an error. If you want the second argument to be treated as a `(1,2)` matrix, you need to reshape it:

```
np.dot(y2,lambda_[0].reshape(1,2))
```

or, alternatively, use a 2D view of `lambda_` instead of a 1D one:

```
np.dot(y2,lambda_[0:1])
```

Comment: out of curiosity do you think recasting y2 and lambda_ as a np.matrix() type would slow it down? i.e. would it be slower to recast a 10000x1 array than 10x1 array?

Comment: I know that `reshape()` creates a view, so it does not depend on the size of the array (since it does not actually copy any data). If `matrix` behaves the same (it's possible), than it shouldn't be too slow either. But I do not see any advantages in using `matrix` here (or anywhere else for that matter, now that Python 3.5 has the dot operator).

Answer (score 1):

Though with numpy it is too easy. You can do with python as below.

```
def array_mult(A, B):
    if len(B) != len(A[0]) and len(A) != len(B[0]):
        return 'Invalid'

    result = [[0 for x in range(len(B[0]))] for y in range(len(A))]
    for i in range(len(A)):
        for j in range(len(B[0])):
            for k in range(len(B)):
                result[i][j] += A[i][k] * B[k][j]
    return result
```